# instance method presentModalViewController:animated not found

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am implementing email composer in app delegate.
I am not sure why , but i am getting an warning

> "instance method  presentModalViewController:animated not found"

only at the appdelegate,whereas, i am using the the same method in my other viewcontroller, which works smoothly.

```
  MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]; 
  mail.mailComposeDelegate = self; 

  if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) 
  {
     //Setting up the Subject, recipients, and message body.

     [mail setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"abc@gmail.com",nil]];
     UIImage *pic = [UIImage imageNamed:@"page0.png"];
     NSData *exportData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pic ,1.0);
     [mail addAttachmentData:exportData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"Picture.jpeg"];

     [mail setSubject:@"dummy text"];
     [mail setMessageBody:@"Please tell us what your concerns are and we will try to fix them" isHTML:NO];
     //Present the mail view controller
     [self presentModalViewController:mail animated:YES]; 
     //release the mail [mail release];
  }
```

`[self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];` this is giving warning and app gets crashed,when reach here.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

```
[self presentModalViewController:mail animated:YES];
```

is UIViewControllers Method . Please check whether you have extended your class from UIViewController

```
@interface abc : UIViewController
```

Answer (score 1):

@NiravPatel: Thanks. You gave me the clue. But i had to replace "mail" by "mailer" in my case.

So, I got it work under iOS7 with

```
[self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

presentModalViewController is a method for `UIViewController`'s subclass and not for `appDelegate`, since it do not have any view controller of itself.

What you can do is, present it to last view controller of navigation controller if you are using that

Answer (score 0):

Why implement this in your app delegate. I would just make a separate view and put whatever your AppDelegate is doing on the view and then implement this code in the viewcontroller. Trying to implement code like PresentModalViewController is not possible in a AppDelegate. Just create a new view and point the app delegate to load that view on startup.

Answer (score 0):

`presentModalViewController:animated:` won't work because `that's method` of `UIViewController` but `self` here is an `app delegate`.

Refer [View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457) link for more reference

Answer (score 0):

it is because that   presentModalViewController is deprecated in ios 6.so for ios 6 you have to write the method like below

```
[self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:nil];
```

let me know it is working or not...!!!!

Happy Coding!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks nirav, but it didnt worked for me.I guess i hv to move my method to view controller.